# How does scaled conjugate gradient work in neural network training? Comparison with gradient descent

Tags: regression, neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am very new and beginner in the machine learning world, and I would like to ask if someone could simply explain to me how does the **scaled conjugate gradient method** work in **neural network training**? Especially in comparison with the gradient descent method, because I already understand that one.

I know exactly the steps on how to train a neural network with gradient descent, but in relation to scaled gradient I can only find far too advanced explanations that I can't yet understand.

Comment: Can you link a paper or the sources you're talking about?

Comment: For example here http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html and Andrew Ng's Coursera course "Machine Learning"